# Is there a word that means "to fill with (positive) apprehension"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to say that a scenario is at once exciting, but also fills me with apprehension. While I could say, "That's both exciting and fills me with apprehension," I would like to use a single word in this place.

But it's a positive sort of apprehension. The sort of apprehension you might feel before going on stage to perform - obviously people are there to see you and so unless you really screw it up it will go well, but still.

Comment: I don't think apprehension is ever positive. And I can tell you from my own experience, it's never a "good" feeling to have before going on stage to perform. Once there I lose the apprehension as I warm to the performance. I think the positive pre-performance feeling would be simply *excitement*.

Comment: @Robusto I agree. imho apprehension has no positive meaning. It's like anxiety.

Comment: So something like a positive apprehension, then :)

Comment: Try tension.  But I think you'll need modifiers too.

Answer (score 1):

Words such as [invigorating](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/invigorate), [energizing](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/energizing), or [exhilarating](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exhilarate) might be used to describe the positive adrenaline rush that can result from stress and apprehension.

Answer (score 0):

**"eagerness"** has a positive connotation and seems to fit.

> eager -  "feeling a strong and impatient desire to do something or for something." [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eager), "having or showing keen interest, intense desire, or impatient expectancy." [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/eagerness)

- "the young actor **was filled with eagerness** to go onstage"
- "She was eager to get started"
- "These students show eagerness to succeed"

Comment: That expresses *being* filled with anticipation. The question is for a verb describing the object of the eagerness.

Answer (score 0):

Before going on stage to perform, you feel

**geared up**

> 15c. to arouse or excite, as with enthusiasm or expectation: *The
>   employees were geared up for a hard battle with management over
>   working hours*.  -Random House